# php odbc close connection is not working properly

Tags: php

The connection cannot close after i open it. Anyone knows how to solve my problem?
I have search a lot of possible answer but no one solve it. 
This is my code

```
<?php 
include 'db.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
$res = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
while(odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    # .....
}
odbc_close($conn);
if (odbc_close($conn)) {
 echo "Connection closed";
}else{
  echo "Connection was not close";
}
?>
```

It says The connection was not close.

Comment: You are closing the connection twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put `odbc_close($conn)` in if condition. It never returns anything. its return type is void so if condition will never return true for this.

for more reference please read this.
[PHP.net odbc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-close.php)

you can use `is_resource($con)`. it gives false if the connection is closed.

Comment: @garwa how can i check if the connection is close? thanks.

Comment: You can use is_resource($con)

Comment: Is it working correct for you? if yes then please accept my answer

Comment: yes this works for me. but the main problem is the connection cannot close.

Comment: Would you please specify the question. you want to close connection or not? if yes then above mentioned function is closing the connection. if not then how you are checking wether its working or not.